# Algorithm for sum of integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

I have to create method which from array of numbers selects numbers, which sum will be exact as required one or if such doesn't exist select the minimal greater one.
What would be the algorithm of this function?

```
public int[] selectExactSum(int[] X, int SUM) {
}
```

example:
numbers are: {5, 2, 8, 4, 6} and required sum is 12.

The result would be: {2, 4, 6}

If required sum is 13, the result would be:{2, 8, 4} - so, the sum would be in this case 14 - the first minimal greater one.

If Required sum is 15, the possible results would be: {5, 2, 8} or {5, 4, 6}. In this case return the one of your choice - probably the first one you get.

What would be the algorithm for custom numbers and sum?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: What do you think would be the approach @Simonxy. Did you think of something?

Comment: Homework? If yes, please add a tag `homework`

Comment: In the example with sum=12, there are several solutions (2,4,6 but also 8,4). Should find them all? Otherwise, are the two solutions equivalent or one is better than the other?

Comment: Interesting question. Don't see why it is practical, but might as well work with it

Comment: [First try to create your own algorithm and post question when you not succeeded.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128572/176299)

Comment: Why wouldn't the required sum 13 return {5, 2, 6} which actually is 13?

Answer (score 6):

This is a generalized case of the problem called [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It's an NP-complete problem, thus the best known algorithm is [pseudo-polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution). 
If you understand the above linked algorithm, you can deduct the modification necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have some example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about recursively?

```
public static int[] SelectExactSum(int[] x, int sum) {
  int[]
    rest = x.Skip(1).ToArray(),
    with = x.Length == 1 ? x : x.Take(1).Concat(SelectExactSum(rest, sum - x[0])).ToArray(),
    without = x.Length == 1 ? new int[0] : SelectExactSum(rest, sum);
  int withSum = with.Sum(), withoutSum = without.Sum();
  return
    withSum >= sum ? (withoutSum >= sum ? (withSum < withoutSum ? with : without) : with) :
    withoutSum >= sum ? without : new int[0];
}
```

Note: Calling `SelectExactSum(new int[] {5,2,8,4,6}, 13)` doesn't return {2,8,4} as stated in the question, but {5,8} as that actually sums up to 13.

Comment: By this way you killing the memory : `int[] rest = ..., with = ..., without  = ...` and recursive calls.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Performace becomes a problem looooong before memory does. For an array with 20 values the maximum memory usage is around 2 kb.

Answer (score 0):

Took me about 15 minutes to made it, you can see it running here:

http://jesuso.net/projects/selectExactSum/index.php?numbers=5%2C2%2C8%2C4%2C6&reqSum=15

And here's the code:

http://jesuso.net/projects/selectExactSum/selectExactSum.txt

I made it as simple as possible, but its made on PHP, let me know if you need some help translating it to c#.

Comment: Note*: Made it just to put you on one of the many ways to do this, of course there are "better" ways to approach this, you would still have to add error handling and stuff like that, but I kinda liked that testing it at the end you can use something like: http://jesuso.net/projects/selectExactSum/index.php?numbers=5%2C2%2C8%2C4%2C6&reqSum=105 and it still works :D

So you can sum ANY number as long as you have 1 pair and 1 odd number, or just a 1 into the given numbers.

Comment: You can post your codes in ideone.com

Comment: As I read your code(I'm not php), I'm not sure if it is working.
Can you explain it in JavaScript or C#?

Comment: the site this answer links to is gone, it would be more useful to paste the relevant code into this answer.  and yes, a c# (or python, or ruby .. ) version would be very helpful to many!